# Block data vs. Entity data in draftjs

Tags: draftjs

I have been confused by the meaning of block data and entity data in draftjs.
Such as the pic below shown.

Why we use entity to store the `src` attribute?

Why not use the `blocks[1].data` object to store `src` attribute?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

refer to `draftjs` [design](https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-entities.html). `entity` can cross over `block`s.  A block is a html paragraph regularly, consider user may select a range cross multiple paragraphs, so we need `entity`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That means entity is represent "inline" element.